# Tikz ornaments at top left or top right corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, page

I want to just place simple object on the corners of each page (and to be able to exclude some pages. I can even do it manually for each page as they are really few), with the usual notation:

```
\newpgfornamentfamily{pgfhan}
\pgfornament[width = 2cm, color = black!]{5}
```

or

```
\newpgfornamentfamily{pgfhan}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={
fill=black!,
fill opacity=1,
line width=0.1pt}}%
\pgfornament[color=black!,scale=0.45,anchor=south, symmetry=v]{5}%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

An example of working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\newpgfornamentfamily{pgfhan}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={
fill=black!,
fill opacity=1,
line width=0.1pt}}%
\pgfornament[color=black!,scale=0.45,anchor=south]{5}%
\end{tikzpicture}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{
\begin{center}
Contenuti
\end{center}}
\tableofcontents

\section{a}
\end{document}
```

I read online a lot of stuff, but most are inside convolved examples I can't split in little parts and identify what I need.

Can you help me?

Comment: please make all your code fragments complete (a minimal working example - MWE) including the document class you are using and ONLY the packages required to replicate your problem. I could also benefit from some drawing or sketch or what you want the result to looklike. Thanks

Comment: Most likely, you can just use `\AddToHook{shipout/background}` and place a `tikzpicture` at the background of the page. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642020/47927

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a fully working example, here is one. I assume you want each corner to have individual pgfornament. Define a new command `\addpgfornaments` contain code of drawing four pgfornaments on each corner. Use this command inside `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\addpgfornaments}` to add drawing in each page and switch off the pgfornaments drawing on corresponding page using `\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}` then switch back on using `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\addpgfornaments}` again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{loopcount}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\newpgfornamentfamily{pgfhan}
\newcommand{\addpgfornaments}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture, 
overlay,
pgfornamentstyle/.style={scale=0.45}
]
\node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament {5}};
\node [anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {\pgfornament[symmetry=h] {5}};
\node [anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) {\pgfornament[symmetry=v] {5}};
\node [anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south east) {\pgfornament[symmetry=v,symmetry=h] {5}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\addpgfornaments}
\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{
\begin{center}
Contenuti
\end{center}}
\tableofcontents

\loop\ifnum\value{loopcount}<30
\stepcounter{loopcount}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{testing}\repeat

\clearpage\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}
\section{a}\clearpage
\section{b}\clearpage\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\addpgfornaments}
\section{c}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]